powerpoint vba Dim attribute incorrect
I was asked to make the code on a previous question shorter.  I have done that but I wanted to show how I get to the Dim attribute and that takes a little bit of code.  So I hope this helps a little.
I have a powerpoint with one slide, one shape (textbox) containing the string "Hello There". Originally the text is set to purple. Then in the animation upon entry (on click on the page) i change the text to green. When I click again (i am done) i change the text to yellow (that is the Dim attribute on the event). I also added "Until Next Click" on the timing tab. This works as expected when I run the slide show. In the final analysis I have two lines in my code:
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(1).EffectInformation.Dim

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).AnimationSettings.DimColor.RGB

These lines should report back a color of yellow but they report back "rgb(53, 106, 149) [darkerblue]".  I don't even know where that color is coming from!
Here is the vba routine. I want that routine to find the yellow phrase. I have code that looks like this which is completely useless in that it doesn't tell how I get to animation settings Dim Color or effect information dim color :
            Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Animation Dim: ", .AnimationSettings.DimColor.RGB)   
                tempVarX = "Dim"
                bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectInformation)
                If bX = True Then
  Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Information Dim: ", tempVarX) '<==========
                End If

End Sub


The output looks like:
lides: 15
key: [00000099200200000000sldc 0000] value: [1]
======== NEW SLIDE =====================
Slide: 1
Slide ID: 448
Slide Name: Slide193
Slide Number: 1
Slide Shapes: 1
Shape: 1
    Shape ID: 3
    Shape Name: TextBox 2
    Shape Title: 
    Shape   Type: 17 (TextBox)
    Visible: True
    Font
        Font Name: Century Gothic
        Text Hello There
    Frame 1
        Text Range
                Range Text: Hello There  
                Color:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
        Paragraphs: 1
        Paragraph: 1 < 1<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        RGB:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
                Bullet
                        RGB:  0 {rgb(0, 0, 0)} [black]
    Frame 2
        Text Range
        Paragraphs: 1
        Paragraph: 1 < 2<<<<<<<<<<<<
                Back RGB:  16777215 {rgb(255, 255, 255)} [white]
                Fore RGB:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
    Animation
        Entry Effect: 257 (Cut)
        After Effect: 0 (No effect)
        Animation Dim:  9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue]  <=========================================
Slide Main Sequence Effects: 1
Effect: 1
    Effect Paragraph: 1
    Shape: TextBox 2
    Effect Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
        Effect Exit: False
    Parameters
        Parameter Color2:  65280 {rgb(0, 255, 0)} [green]
    Information
        Information Effect: 1 (Hides)
        Information Dim:  9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue] <=============================================
    Behaviors: 1
    Behavior: 1
        Behavior Type: 8 (Set)
        Behavior Set Effect Property: 101 (Text font color}
        Behavior Set Effect To Color:  65280 {rgb(0, 255, 0)} [green]

and here is the problem: Dim is reported as darker blue "Information Dim: 9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue]" I don't know why Dim isn't being reported as yellow and I do not know where the darker blue is coming from.

What is the difference to your previous question?

shorter source code

Please don't open a new question, edit your question instead. btw the code is still long.

i do not know how to edit a question -- two lines of code is still too long???????  I have seen this happen many times here and other places.  "Don't help anybody just criticize their question!!"

Just to clarify, dimming happens automatically after an animation is finished, it's not something you trigger (Effect Options>Effect>After animation). I'm confused by your description "When I click again (i am done) i change the text to yellow (that is the Dim attribute on the event)." It sounds like you're adding another animation to change to yellow, not dimming to yellow.

All of the animation is setup using powerpoint animation pane.  It has one item (with an id of "hello there") It is started "OnClick" uaing Font change.  On the effects options dialog I set Settings/Font Color to Green (rgb(0,255,0)) (and solid)l.  In the Enhancement part of the dialog I set After Animation to Yellow (rgb(255,255,0)).  When i run slide show it "hello there" starts out purple, when i click on the slide the text turns to green, and when I click on the slide againt the text turns to yellow.  In the VBA program I want to access (read) the animation "properties"
